# How to know if external application was closed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I say if a winform whas closed do ...?

```
bool isRunning = false;
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) 
{
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("Notepad"))
    {
        isRunning = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The code above always checks if the process exists but the code is slow for what I want it to do.So is there a way to check if the `Notepad` process was actually closed instead of always looping to see if its there?

Comment: Did you launch the process? if so you could keep the variable from that and check the process is still running much quicker

Comment: I wont launch it from code.

Comment: @PrasanthVJ but hes just confirmed hes not launching the notepad... so this doesnt apply

Comment: @PrasanthVJ The answer in that link assumes you have started the process from code, the OP does not do this

Comment: @JohnPietrar do you just need to know if there are any notepads, or just existing ones close?

Comment: If the existing one closed

Comment: Then create a list of offending processes that match notepad (and any other things you need closing) and you can then loop over that list and if they drop off, remove it till the length of the list is 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680488/how-can-i-capture-all-application-window-messages-from-start-of-process somewhat helpful?

Comment: Never use `Contains` when comparing process names. You need to make sure that this is exactly the process you are looking for so use equality or `Compare`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Win32_ProcessStopTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstoptrace?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which indicates that a process is terminated.

```
ManagementEventWatcher watcher;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("Select * From Win32_ProcessStopTrace");
    watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
    watcher.Start();
}

void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"] == "notepad.exe")
        MessageBox.Show("Notepad closed");
}

protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    watcher.Stop();
    watcher.Dispose();
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
```

Don't forget to add a reference to `System.Management` and add `using System.Management;`

**Note**

- If you want to monitor closing of an specific instance of notepad which you know, you can use such criteria:

  ```
  if ((UInt32)e.NewEvent["ProcessID"]==knownProcessId)
  ```
- If you want to check if any instance of notepad is open, you can use such criteria:

  ```
  if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Any())
  ```
- The `EventArrived` will raise in a different thread than UI thread and if you need to manipulate UI, you need to use `Invoke`.
- Above method notifies you about closing of all processes, regardless of the time they are opened, before or after your application run. If you don't want to notified about the processes which may be opened after your application starts, you can get existing notepad processes and subscribe to their `Exited` event:

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").ToList()
            .ForEach(p => {
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.Exited += p_Exited;
            });
  }
  void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Notepad closed");
  }
  ```

Comment: this will tell you if a notepad had closed but there still could be another notepad open.

Comment: If you want to know if all notepad executables have closed than in the EventArrived event check again if still any notepad is open using GetProcessByName. That way you are sure all notepads are closed.

Comment: If you want to monitor closing of an specific instance of notepad which you know, you can use such criteria: `if ((UInt32)e.NewEvent["ProcessID"]==knownProcessId)`. The post shows how to detect closing of a process, instead of manually checking if the process is running.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it without looping but dont know if its much faster :

```
bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("NotePad").FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

or

```
bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Any();
```

I got this from here [Check if a specific exe file is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742787/check-if-a-specific-exe-file-is-running)

Comment: You can also use `Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Any()` which returns `true` if there is any `notepad` process running. I added *Note* part based on your  comment.

Comment: offcourse you are right. The Any() saves me an additional check on != null.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. It will create a event for you when the process dies. No need to loop through all the process.

```
public static event EventHandler ProcessDied;
public void CheckForProcess()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    ProcessDied += new EventHandler(Process_Died);
    AttachProcessDiedEvent("notepad", ProcessDied);

}

private  void AttachProcessDiedEvent( string processName,EventHandler e )
{
    Process isSelectedProcess=null;
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(processName))
        {
            isSelectedProcess = clsProcess;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isSelectedProcess!=null)
    {
         isSelectedProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
    if(e!=null)
    {
        e.Invoke(processName, new EventArgs());
    }
}

private void Process_Died(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Your work
}
```

Let me know if there are any issues.