# application closes itself when another program closes?

Tags: vb.net

Basically I have my "monitor" and I'm playing and the executable is "Game.exe" (Rpg Maker xp). I want my "monitor" to close itself after Game.exe is killed or terminated. If I can, how should I do this properly?
Sorry horrible english

Comment: [Detect closing of the other process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703399/how-to-know-if-external-winform-was-closed), then [exit the application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out whether your "target process" is still running:

```
Dim gameStillRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("Game").Any()
```

How to trigger the end of your own application depends on the nature of your monitoring application:

- If it's a GUI application, set a timer that frequently checks if Game is still running.
- If your application has no other purpose than to wait until Game has been closed (or if you have a dedicated thread for this purpose), you can use [`p.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) on the process `p` obtained by `GetProcessesByName`.