# Getting a NotSupportedException when trying to close my Form

Tags: c#, winforms

As you can see in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39704027/6886308 ,you can tell when an winform was closed like in the example ,the `Notepad`.
And I tried playing with it a bit and while the code in the example worked ,something bothered me.

What if I want to close my app when the `Notepad` was closed?So I tried something like:

```
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"] == "notepad.exe")
        {
           Close();
        }
}
```

And it is trowing me an un-handled error ,so I was thinking maybe the focus remained on the winform?Or what is the problem in fact?

#### EDIT 1:

[Here is a screenshot of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntowq.png)

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you are trying to close the process from a thread other than on what it was created on. This is not allowed.

do it like this

```
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"] == "notepad.exe")
        {
           this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {

               Close();
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is on another thread but you're calling Close on your form which isn't allowed - you need to have something like `Invoke((Action)Close);` which will marshall the call back to the UI thread.